# Powershell v2.0 extract substring

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm a novice at using Powershell.  I'm working on a server with Powershell v2.0.

I have a date value assigned to a substring ($d1):  2016-06-08-07.30.03.119000-240

I want to get just the date/time portion:  2016-06-08-07.30.03

I've been able to do the following to get:   2016-06-08-07. 30. 03

```
echo $d1 > $tempfile
$d1a = ( Get-Content $tempfile | %{ $_.Split('.')[0]; } )
$d1b = ( Get-Content $tempfile | %{ $_.Split('.')[1]; } )
$d1c = ( Get-Content $tempfile | %{ $_.Split('.')[2]; } )
$d1 = "$d1a.$d1b.$d1c"
```

Is there a way to get the value that I want without the extra spaces?

I tried:

```
$d1 = ( $d1a, $d1b, $d1c -join "." )
```

but that gives:  System.Object[].System.Object[].System.Object[]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substring you want to extract has a well-defined length (19 characters), so the simplest way would be to use the `Substring()` method:

```
$d1.Substring(0, 19)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!   I had tried Substring before, but kept getting errors, so I must have had my syntax wrong.

Comment: That worked fine from the powershell command line, but when I ran the script, it worked, but also threw the following error:

Comment: `Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'Substring'.
At E:\DBA\Scripts\SchedTasks\Db2diag\diagAnalysis_Extract.ps1:69 char:21
+ $d1a = $d1.Substring <<<< (0, 19)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Substring:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`

Comment: So it actually didn't work ... my output file contained:  db2diag.log Report for  through

Comment: This is very weird ... it worked the first time I tried it on the command line, but it won't work anymore.

`PS C:\Users\ioh1> $d1
2016-06-08-07.30.03.119000-240

PS C:\Users\ioh1> $d1.Substring(0,19)
2016-06-08-07.30.03

PS C:\Users\ioh1> $d1 = $d1.Substring(0, 19)
PS C:\Users\ioh1> $d1
2016-06-08-07.30.03

PS C:\Users\ioh1> $d2 = $d2.Substring(0,19)
PS C:\Users\ioh1> echo "`r`ndb2diag.log Report for $d1 through $d2"

db2diag.log Report for 2016-06-08-07.30.03 through 2016-06-08-07.30.03`

Now I just get the error shown in my previous comment.

Comment: Apparently the value in `$d1` is the result of a `Select-String` operation. Use `$d1.Line.Substring()`, assuming that the line doesn't contain other text. For further help: please post a new question with detailed information about how where the value in the variable comes from.